# How do I filter out data that has duplicate values under a specific column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, survey

I have a table that holds the results of a survey:

```
submitter   issue       q1  q2  q3  q4  q5

mike         11557      4   3   4   5   1
mark         13554      5   5   5   5   5
luke         15110      1   1   1   1   1
luke         15110      1   1   1   1   1
donald       16900      4   2   2   4   5
joe          11562      5   5   5   5   5
joe          11562      5   5   5   5   5
sam          12485      2   3   4   3   4
sam          12485      2   3   4   3   4
sam          12485      2   3   4   3   4
```

I want to be able to filter out multiple submissions and count only 1 of them.
Some folks submitted 3 or 4 times.

I know how to find out how many times a survey was submitted and by whom:

```
SELECT
    submitter
    ,issue
    ,COUNT(*) as '# of times Survey submitted'

FROM
    Survey

GROUP BY
    submitter, issue

HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

But, I'm not sure how I can use this query to filter out the multiple submissions.

The current query I am working with is:

```
SELECT 'Question #1' as 'Survey Question'
,CAST(CAST(SUM(q1) AS float)/COUNT(q1) AS decimal (4,2)) as 'Average Score'

FROM Survey
WHERE COALESCE(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5) IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Question #2' as 'Survey Question'
,CAST(CAST(SUM(q2) AS float)/COUNT(q2) AS decimal (4,2)) as 'Average Score'
FROM Survey
WHERE COALESCE(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5) IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

etc...
```

The desired outcome is:  (Note: this result set is not accurate.  Just format i would like to have.)

```
Survey Question Average Score
Question #1      4.58
Question #2      4.80
Question #3      4.60
Question #4      4.59
Question #5      4.64
```

Can anyone provide a clue?

Thanks so much!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: How do you decide which one of the multi-submissions you will count? Please also show your expected outcome

Comment: The submissions are all the same (from any particular user) so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got the math right, but my results don't match yours exactly. Are you sure your desired results are correct?

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (submitter VARCHAR(10), Issue INT, q1 TINYINT, q2 TINYINT,q3 TINYINT, q4 TINYINT,q5 TINYINT);
INSERT INTO @yourTable
VALUES  ('mike',11557,4,3,4,5,1),
        ('mark',13554,5,5,5,5,5),
        ('luke',15110,1,1,1,1,1),
        ('luke',15110,1,1,1,1,1),
        ('donald',16900,4,2,2,4,5),
        ('joe',11562,5,5,5,5,5),
        ('joe',11562,5,5,5,5,5),
        ('sam',12485,2,3,4,3,4),
        ('sam',12485,2,3,4,3,4),
        ('sam',12485,2,3,4,3,4);

WITH CTE_Distinct
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM @yourTable  --just change this to your actual table name.
)

SELECT  REPLACE(question,'q','Question #')   AS [Survey Question],
        CAST(AVG(val * 1.0) AS DECIMAL(4,2)) AS [Average Score]
FROM CTE_Distinct
UNPIVOT
(
    val FOR question IN (q1,q2,q3,q4,q5)
) unpvt
GROUP BY question
```

Results:

```
Survey Question     Average Score
-------------------- ---------------------------------------
Question #1          3.50
Question #2          3.17
Question #3          3.50
Question #4          3.83
Question #5          3.50
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Stephan.  How would I query the DB for the values of the survey rather than enter them in like you did?

Comment: Just change @yourTable to your actual table name. And obviously you don't have to declare it or insert the values  so you can delete those parts.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH TestData AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        ('Mike', 11557, 4, 3, 4, 5, 1)
      , ('Mark', 13554, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5)
      , ('Luke', 15110, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
      , ('Luke', 15110, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
      , ('Donald', 16900, 4, 2, 2, 4, 5)
      , ('Joe', 11562, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
      , ('Joe', 11562, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
      , ('Sam', 12485, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4)    
      , ('Sam', 12485, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4)    
      , ('Sam', 12485, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4)    
    ) A (Submitter, Issue, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5)
)
SELECT SurveyQuestion
     , AverageScore = AVG(QuestionAnswer * 1.) -- Change the math here if this isn't what you want 
FROM (    
    SELECT A.Submitter
         , A.Issue
         , B.SurveyQuestion
         , B.QuestionAnswer
         , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.Submitter, A.Issue, B.SurveyQuestion ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -- Replace ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) with something more meaningful if you can
    FROM TestData A
    CROSS APPLY(VALUES -- Unpivot
        ('Question #1', A.Q1)
      , ('Question #2', A.Q2)
      , ('Question #3', A.Q3)
      , ('Question #4', A.Q4)
      , ('Question #5', A.Q5)
    ) B (SurveyQuestion, QuestionAnswer)
    WHERE B.SurveyQuestion IS NOT NULL
) A
WHERE RowNum = 1
GROUP BY SurveyQuestion;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your query Kittoes.  Do you know how I might be able to query the data (values) rather than entering them in?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I assume you're referring to the fact that questions 1-5 are hard coded into the `CROSS APPLY`. The only way to make this part more dynamic would be to write some dynamic SQL. If you're referring to the test data then just throw it into a table and replace `FROM TestData` with `FROM <your table name>`.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the test data.  Thanks again for your help, Kittoes.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution I think you can apply is: *pick the submitter and issue and the max value of every one of the answers given per per sumitter*:

```
    select submitter, issue, 
       (select max(q1) 
           from survey 
          where submitter = parent.submitter 
            and issue = parent.issue) as q1,
       (select max(q2) 
           from survey 
          where submitter = parent.submitter 
            and issue = parent.issue) as q2,
       (select max(q3) 
           from survey 
          where submitter = parent.submitter 
            and issue = parent.issue) as q3,
       (select max(q4) 
           from survey 
          where submitter = parent.submitter 
            and issue = parent.issue) as q4,
       (select max(q5) 
           from survey 
          where submitter = parent.submitter 
            and issue = parent.issue) as q5
from survery as parent
group by submitter, issue;
```

But the problem of this solution is that it gives for example the greatest answers per question, which might not be the desired output.

Another approach passes by adding an id per register:

```
alter table survery add id bigint auto_increment;
```

With an id that marks every line as different, this is fish of another keetle. The select is much, much simpler:

```
    select *
      from survey
      where (submitter, issue, id ) in 
      (
    select submitter, issue, max(id)
      from survey 
     group by submitter, issue);
```

The inner select (the one that haves the group by), identifies what id you want to get, the second select retrieves all the information: submitter, id, and the answers. You can use it with a max() to retrieve the last answer as the *good* answer, or you can use it with a min() to retrieve the first answer.

**Update**

Sorry, I din't read that "average" request you made. In the case you want an average value instead of the answer, I humbly recomend the second approach. The select would be then:

```
    select avg(q1) as avg_q1, 
           avg(q2) as avg_q2, 
           ....
      from survey
      where (submitter, issue, id ) in 
      (
    select submitter, issue, max(id)
      from survey 
     group by submitter, issue);
```